# Textarea autogrow onkeyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

**I am using this script**

```
 jQuery.each(jQuery('textarea[data-autoresize]'), function() {
     var offset = this.offsetHeight - this.clientHeight;

     var resizeTextarea = function(el) {
         jQuery(el).css('height', 'auto').css('height', el.scrollHeight + offset);
     };

     jQuery(this).on('keyup input', function() {
         resizeTextarea(this); }).removeAttr('data-autoresize'); 
     });
  });
```

**and this is my html**

```
<h:inputTextarea id="newUserIds" value="#{surveyAction.newUsers}"
 cols="41" rows="10" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)"
styleClass="animated">
   <p:ajax event="blur" process="@this" immediate="true" />
</h:inputTextarea>
```

How do I target that specific textarea on the javascript so that the action only applies there.

Comment: How do you expect the "autoresize" to work? Resize while typing so that there's no scrollbar?  Should resizing stop on some condition (e.g. height reaches viewport height)? Should it shink? Why to you `removeAttr("data-autoresize")` on `keyup`

Comment: Can you please confirm, that the rendered HTML contains the `data-autoresize` attribute at the `textarea`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current selector doesn't find your textarea element.

Change the jQuery selector from `textarea[data-autoresize]` to `#newUserIds`, or change your textarea tag and add the attribute `data-autoresize` (recommended):

```
<h:inputTextarea id="newUserIds" value="#{surveyAction.newUsers}" cols="41" rows="10" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)" styleClass="animated">
```

Comment: Not necessarily. It looks like the TO is using JSF, maybe thats attribute is automatically rendered into HTML? (Btw: is still missing in your answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Use a content editable div instead. For setting the values to your back end component, use a input type="hidden" field.

See - http://jsfiddle.net/gy6gdn59/6/

CSS -

```
.resizable{
    overflow-x:auto;
    border:1px solid #AAA;
    min-height: 50px;
    resize: both;
}
```

Markup-

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="resizable" id="resizablePseudoInput">
</div>
```